# Combine lines whenever string matches in the first field

Tags: notepad++, regex

Combine lines with matching first field
I have a long text file which consists of lines in the following format:

Groub 1

```
any|word،some other word،more word
any word|word2،other word،more word،more
any text|word4،some word،other word
```

Groub 2

```
Line contain any
line contain any word
line contain any text
```

and would like to convert it to

```
any|some text،some other text،more text|Lines contain any
any word|text،other text،more text،more|lines contain any word
any text|word4،some word،other word|lines contain any text
```

Is it possible to do this in Notepad++ with Regex?

Comment: Your repeated use of the same word roots to identify different strings makes it vbery confusing to identify matches and differences.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with regex.

Most likely you need a script written in a language such as Python to do this.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Toto: I disagree. Not being possible is the answer to the question asked: "Is it possible to do this in Notepad++ with Regex?"